# smarty concatanate a var from a file and a normal smarty one in the smarty include section

Tags: smarty, smarty3, smarty2

Hi I am trying to evaluate a variable from a file and a normal one but seems to be harder than it looks so :

This works:

```
{config_load file="archive_page.conf"
section="profile"} {include file="header.tpl" title=#pageTitle# keywords=#keywords# description=#description#}
```

I would like to also use my var and concatenate the text together so the below doesn't work also I have tried variations with '', "" but leads either an error message or one of the variables to display as text...

```
{config_load file="archive_page.conf"
section="profile"} {include file="header.tpl" title=#pageTitle#$MYVARHERE keywords=#keywords# description=#description#}
```

I tried various things but I can't get it to work, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [cat variable modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.cat.tpl):

```
title=#pageTitle#|cat:$MYVARHERE
```